# Export to xml using jQuery works from jsfiddle but not from browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to export HTML table content in xls. I found a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/jWAJ7/) but when I am using same approach the export works from fiddle but not from browser (IE11 & chrome version 54) through company network.

The fiddle I am trying is [my example](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddle300/fowy57q1/1/) and code for same is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Summary</title>
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#dvData').html());
    e.preventDefault();
});
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <h1>Summary</h1>
    </center>

    <input type="button" id="btnExport" value=" Export Table data into Excel " />
    <div id="dvData">
    <table>
      <tr><th>ColTitle</th><th>Column1</th><th>Title2</th><th>Title3</th><th>Title4</th><th>Title5</th><th>Title6</th><th>Title7</th><th>Title8</th><th>Title9</th><th>Title10</th><th>Title11</th></tr>
      <tr><td>Title1</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>33</td><td align=center>667</td><td align=center>45</td><td align=center>45</td><td align=center>45</td><td align=center>45</td><td align=center>4</td><td align=center>76</td><td align=center>45</td><td align=center>0</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Title2</td><td align=center>56</td><td align=center>34</td><td align=center>9</td><td align=center>83</td><td align=center>6</td><td align=center>70</td><td align=center>458</td><td align=center>76</td><td align=center>23</td><td align=center>6</td><td align=center>43</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Title3</td><td align=center>9</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>341</td><td align=center>11</td><td align=center>77</td><td align=center>121</td><td align=center>7</td><td align=center>3</td><td align=center>67</td><td align=center>190</td><td align=center>66</td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>  

  </body>
</html>
```

I think somehow because of company network the jquery library is not getting loaded but I can't confirm it as I don't see any error through chrome -> inspect.

Has anyone faced same problem and know how to resolve it? Or even some tips on how I can find where the problem is would be helpful.

Comment: look at the JSFiddle Javascript pane options, it is set run on onDomReady, meaning the code in it won't run till the ondomready event fires, your code doesn't do that.

Comment: `#btnExport` doesn't exist at the time you're running the script.

Comment: Thank you Patric Evans and Teemu. I had totally missed to check Load Type option on JavaScript pane. After I added that option to fiddle as well as in code, it now works for chrome but not IE11. I can still accept this as answer but don't see that option for your comment.